# How to find records that violates foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, referential-integrity

I'm trying to find records that is violating the ORA-02291: integrity constraint::

I was running this query, But I didnt get any results back::

```
    SELECT child.parent_id
    FROM child LEFT JOIN parent ON child.parent_id = parent.parent_id
    WHERE parent.parent_id IS NULL;
```

Am I missing something or what are the other ways to find the records which are violating these constraints.

Comment: Is the constraint violation occurring when you try to insert data?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select parent_id
from child c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from parent p
    where p.id = c.parent_id)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6881a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to **delete orphan records** in child table to be able to make the foreign key constraints :

```
DELETE FROM `child`
WHERE `parent_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `id`
    FROM `parent`
);
```